# What is a 'post' on Stack Overflow pages?

Tags: support

When going through my badges to track, I encountered the badge *[Excavator](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/what-are-the-badges-i-can-earn-on-each-site-and-what-are-the-exact-criteria-for/188732#188732)* - "Edit first post that was inactive for more than 6 months."

It is not clear to me what a *post* is. In my profile I can find *questions* and *answers*. Within questions, I might find comments.

In my profile, I found a "you don't follow any posts".

Comment: Both questions and answers are posts.

Comment: Also see "Post" in meta.SE glossary of common terms: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/40353/756727

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The term "post" encompasses both questions and answers.

Only questions, answers, and articles are *subsets* of posts.

Things that are *not* considered "posts" are comments.

Comment: Except the fact that articles _ARE_ considered posts?

Comment: @Nick wait, are they? I was under the impression they weren't.

Comment: Their revisions are accessed at: `/posts/<article_id>/revisions`, the edit short link is (or was, when we were allowed to edit them) `/posts/<article_id>/edit`, they're accessible through all of `/questions/<article_id>`, `/q/<article_id>`, `/a/<article_id>`. That all kinda indicates that they're posts. Also just the type of content that they are :p